# Show previous value in input, but allow immediate typing of new value or accept previous value

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have 3 input fields used for 10-key data entry.  The `+` key is used to tab to the next input field.

When the user is on the last input, the data is appended to an array and the process starts over with the focus being moved to the first field.

The user would like to have the previous value as a default value, so that if the entry does not need to change, all they have to do is press the `+` button to accept the value.  But if it *does* need to change, they want to just start typing.

...and I have to support IE 11.

What I have tried:

- Not clearing previous value-- leaves focus at end of the input, which appends new input instead of clearing value first.
- Copying previous value into placeholder-- shows the value and allows immediate typing.  If `+` is pressed without entering a value, copy previous value into field. This works; but unfortunately [IE doesn't show placeholders](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) if focus is on the input.

```js
/**
 * Declare 'Global' variables
 * 
 * transactions array is an array of transaction objects. It is the
 * storage container of transactions before submission to database
 *
 * typeSummary{} is an associative array that aggregates totals based on type, ie,
 * typeSummary.type = running total for that type
 *
 * transactionIndex gives an index for identifying the row number of a transaction.
 */
    var transactions = [];
    var transactionIndex = 0;

    // ...snip...

/**
 *
 *  EVENT LISTENERS
 *
 *      Keypresses on Inputs: advance to next input and store data structure before starting back at beginning
 *      Transaction Delete: 
 */
$(document).ready(function(){

  /**
   * Listener for data entry fields [account | type | amount]
   *
   * Uses the '+' key (43) to advance to the next field.  
   * Values are stored in global array 'transactions' upon
   * advancing cursor back to position 1 (account)
   *
   * tried various JS ways to advance cursor, such as 
   *   var inputs = $(this).closest('.form-group').find(':input');
   *   inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
   *   or
   *   $(this).nextAll().find('.inputs:first').focus();
   * but most reliable way is to procedurally advance to the next one I designate by means of id.
   */
  $('.inputs').keypress(function (e) {

    // advance on '+' key
    if(e.which==43) {

      // prevent entry from being entered into input
      e.preventDefault();

      if(this.id=='account') {

        fillDefaultAccountNumber();

        console.log('advancing focus from account to type');
        $('#type').focus();
      }

      if(this.id=='type') {
        
        console.log('advancing focus from type to amount');
        $('#amount').focus();
      }

      if(this.id=='amount') {

        //addRecord();
        
        clearInputs();
        transactionIndex++;

        console.log('advancing focus from amount back to account');
        $('#account').focus();

      }

    }


  });

});


function clearInputs() {
      
  var val = $('#account').val();
  $('#account').attr("placeholder", val);
  
  $('#account').val('');
  $('#type').val('');
  $('#amount').val('');
}

/**
 *
 * if there was a placeholder and no value was entered,
 * use placeholder value to fill in value.
 *
 */
function fillDefaultAccountNumber() {
      
  if($('#account').val()=='') {
    
    $('#account').val($('#account').attr('placeholder'));
    
    console.log('No value entered; using placeholder.');
    console.log('Account value is now ' + $('#account').val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Press 'plus' key to advance to next field</h3>
<div class= "panel panel-default">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend panel-heading>Transaction Entry</legend>
          <form class="form-horizontal panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="account" class="col-sm-5">Account (9 digits)</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7"><input id="account" class="inputs" type="text" autofocus maxlength="9" size="9" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="type" class="col-sm-5">Type (1 digit)</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7"><input id="type" class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="amount" class="col-sm-5">Amount</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7"><input id="amount" class="inputs lastInSeries" type="text" /></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
<h3>Press 'plus' key to start next record</h3>
```

This snippet works the way I want; does anyone know how to make this work with IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix.

1. Leave the value of `#account` unchanged.
2. Select it.  This selects the entire value as if you tabbed to it, and allows immediate typing or accepting of the value.

   ```
   $('.inputs').keypress(function (e) {

     // advance on '+' key
     if(e.which==43) {

       // prevent entry from being entered into input
       e.preventDefault();

       if(this.id=='account') {

         //fillDefaultAccountNumber();

         console.log('advancing focus from account to type');
         $('#type').focus();
       }

       if(this.id=='type') {

         console.log('advancing focus from type to amount');
         $('#amount').focus();
       }

       if(this.id=='amount') {

         addRecord();

         console.log('advancing focus from amount back to account');
         $('#account').focus();
         $('#account').select(); // allows default value to be accepted or start typing new value.

       }

     }
   ```